# Как создать вложенный словарь?

Tags: python, словари, dict

Вот из этого

```
['2018-01-01', 'yandex', 'cpc', 100]
```

Надо получить вот это

```
{'2018-01-01': {'yandex': {'cpc': 100}}}
```

Причем список может расширяться до бесконечности.
Подскажите плиз чего почитать хоть?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чуть более элегантное на мой взгляд решение, через рекурсию и распаковку:

```py
def to_dict(list_: list):
    first, *rest = list_
    return {first: to_dict(rest)} if rest else first

lst = ['2018-01-01', 'yandex', 'cpc', 100]

print(to_dict(lst))
```

Плюс красивый вариант @insolor без рекурсии в переделке на тот же лад с распаковкой:

```py
def to_dict(list_: list):
    result, *rest = reversed(list_)
    for i in rest:
        result = {i: result}
    return result
```

Comment: Элегантно, вот только если первое с ходу понятно, то это - совсем нет:-)

Comment: @Сергей Мне казалось, что названия переменных помогают в понимании происходящего )

Comment: да, это так. Но надо помнить ещё как `*` работает и сопоставить с работой тернарного оператора. Потому и говорю, что элегантнее/интереснее, но сложнее.

Answer (score 5):

Прочитать: (1) рекурсия. (2) slicing.

```
def to_dict(l):
     if len(l) == 2 :
          return { l[0] : l[1] }
     else:
          return { l[0] : to_dict( l[1:] ) }
```

Answer (score 5):

Без рекурсии - просто итерируемся от конца списка, каждый предыдущий частичный результат оборачиваем в новый словарь:

```
def to_dict(s: list):
    result = s[-1]

    for i in reversed(range(len(s) - 1)):
        result = {s[i]: result}
        
    return result


print(to_dict(['2018-01-01', 'yandex', 'cpc', 100]))
```